# Correct way to capture event.target when a child element is clicked

Tags: javascript

I want to call a javascript function when an anchor is clicked and capture the element's href & title attributes. My code works fine if the content of the element is plaintext but when I introduce new elements inside of the anchor tag such as a label & icon then e.target is now the label or icon so I can no longer get the href attribute.

I can write some code that checks the element type and if it's not an anchor find the parent but I'm wondering if there's a better way for my function to get the anchor element from event.target even if a sub element is clicked?

```js
function doStuff(e) {
  console.log(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
  console.log(e.target.getAttribute("title"));
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<a href="/bob" title="Bob" onClick="doStuff(event)">
  <i class='fa fa-user'></i>
  <label>Bob</label>
</a>
```

Comment: You could use [`if(e.target.matches("a:link"))`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) (or `a[href]` as a selector).

Comment: Use `event.currentTarget`, See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: There has to be a better dupetarget than the one currently selected, though. It *is* a duplicate question, but...

Comment: I was not aware of currentTarget. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you could use `event.currentTarget`, which should give you the anchor element to which you have bound the event

Comment: Many, many dupes easily found

Answer (score -2):

When a sub/child element is clicked, you can get a reference to the parent through : `event.target.offsetParent` .

Comment: [`offsetParent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent) is very much **not** the correct tool for this job.

Comment: thought the question was about getting the parent, mistake on my part

Comment: Slightly, but the offset parent is (often) not the parent.

Comment: should be `parentNode` then?

Comment: Not necessarily. It could be the parent of the parent, or the parent of the parent of the parent. The correct answer is `event.currentTarget`, as pointed out in the comments.